# Could not install packages due to an Subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

I try to install a module `barnaba`.

Recently: 1) setup Python's versions 3.10 and 3.9. Start to use VSC.
2) I updated pip `python3 pip install --upgrade pip`.
`pip install --upgrade pip --user Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\432e\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (24.0)`

ERROR:**subprocess-exited-with-error**
`! pip install barnaba`

```
Collecting barnaba
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      C compiler:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\432E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\432E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\432E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\432E\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mxizmmvo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\432E\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mxizmmvo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\432E\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mxizmmvo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\432E\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mxizmmvo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 56, in <module>
        File ".\basesetup.py", line 45, in initialize
          self._print_compiler_version(cc)
        File ".\basesetup.py", line 108, in _print_compiler_version
...
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

  Using cached barnaba-0.1.9-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\432e\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from barnaba) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\432e\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from barnaba) (1.12.0)
Collecting mdtraj (from barnaba)
  Using cached mdtraj-1.9.9.tar.gz (2.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
```

ERROR:
`! pip install barnaba`

- What do I want? RMSD/eRMSD calculation

```
import barnaba as bb

# define trajectory and topology files
native="./Prot-RNA.pdb"
traj = "./test5/md-removepbc.xtc"
top = "./data.pdb"

# calculate eRMSD between native and all frames in trajectory
ermsd = bb.ermsd(native,traj,topology=top)
```

Comment: It would help to separate the command you have run in separate lines/code blocks. As it is, it is not possible to determine if you are running the `pip install barnaba` command or not